Google Earth Pro not saving elevations
I have terrain turned on, and tested all options for altitude but each time I save the track the elevation is set at zero. I simply use Notepad to examine the output file. Simple test to check what elevation is returned is to view the elevation profile and all this looks fine.
With the save KML showing all values at zero, I imported it into GE and it shows all elevations ok, but is this just GE putting things together by matching the input coordinates to elevation?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In fact I have found that while GE displays elevations and will record and display these on a user defined track, when exporting the track coordinates it specifically omits these. These can be picked up from various terrain models using GPS Visualiser though when converting the GE KML to other formats.
